# Why does the form of this near-identity coordinate transformation imply the space-time is Minkowski and flat?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor

I'm trying to work out the reasoning behind a solution given to a past exam question for my General Relativity exam. I've attached the question here:

[image]

And here is the given solution:

[image]

I managed to derive the correct form of $\epsilon$ myself but am confused as to why implies the space-time is therefore Minkowski. My current thought is that it's something to do with being a gauge transformation but I'm not certain why this might be the case.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You are correct; essentially the weird looking metric is gauge-equivalent to the flat space metric, so it is in fact just that-flat space. In other words, the apparent non-flatness of the metric is just an artifact of the choice of coordinates; not spacetime itself.

Comment: @GRrocks Thank you, your explanation along with taking the time to write out what had confused me seems to have made it all click and I understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the coordinate transformation removes h terms to first order then the metric is just left as 
$$
ds^2 = -c^2dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2 \tag{1}
$$
which is clearly just the Minkowski metric in Cartesian coordinates.

i.e. Its the choice of coordinates used initially that caused it to look 'non-flat' and so with a simple coordinate transformation, you recover flat space.

You could say its the 'y' coordinate initially that's stealthily a non-Cartesian coordinate, but they're just variables after all, so its acceptable. The true Cartesian 'y' coordinate is in the RHS of the coordinate transformation: $`\mathbf{y}+h\varepsilon'$.

Answer (score 0):

Matter/energy =m/e.
Space time. As described by Stephen Hawking, in a forward time frame stated in the theory of everything. Before the Big Bang, the fog of energy, as it was, we realise that space does not need m/e to be space. However m/e needs space to be space so m/e can be in it’s current forms of m/e. With space, you are always in it, but can never touch it. 
The structure of space and m/e from one source (fog) into relevant parts, the structure of space and the structure of m/e.  Both are sealed into what they are. From space to matter into the properties of a blackhole (sphere).
Back to the fog, as described by Hawking, had no where to exist initially, it’s only reference frame is existence or not. Due to where it is or was and it’s previous function, non-existence or existence. Unless there was an assigned area, that place needed to exist also. Once the fog existed, unless it had a time frame reference to reference in regards to keeping or measuring time, the structure of space simply is. And either exists or does not, no outside time frame. Time is not the structure of space but an existence function to the universe, within it. Time A = existence.
Time B.
Quantum, measurable with atomic decay is not based on time, the process can be timed and over time with exposure to energy, but a parameter with energy laws.
Measurable with time B, seasons, atomic decay etc. 
Time A and Time B.